# unable to extract information by web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

http://www.harrods.com/accessories/handbags?viewall=yes

From this webpage, I am trying to get the brand name, bag name, style, material, colors, original price, and sale price of the handbags.

So far, I have this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

saksurl="http://www.harrods.com/accessories/handbags?viewall=yes"
html = urlopen(saksurl)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser")

for product in bsObj.findAll("ul",{"class":"products_row"}):
    product_price = product.find("span",{"class":"price_all plp_price"}).get_text()
    print((product.h3).get_text(),product_price)
```

I am having these kinds of problems:

- Separating the brand names from the bags' names
- I'm getting the prices in Euros for some reason (want them in $)
- I'm not getting prices for some bags
- Separating the original prices from sale prices
- How can I get the colors of the bags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Separating the brand names from the bags' names

Within the `h3` with the brand and name, there is an `a`, and under that are two `span`s, one with the brand, one with the name.

You can easily see this kind of thing using the developer tools in Firefox or Chrome. Right click an element and click 'Inspect [element]'. Much nicer than looking at HTML. Although looking at HTML should have revealed this too.

> - I'm getting the prices in Euros for some reason (want them in $)

There's a country/currency selector at the top. After changing it and inspecting the Network tab in Chrome I found that the new requests contained an additional cookie. This led to the solution:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
...
req = Request(saksurl)
req.add_header('Cookie', 'Country=US; Currency=USD;')
html = urlopen(req)
```

> - I'm not getting prices for some bags

Each `products_row` can contain multiple bags, typically 3, each in a `li` tag. Again, look more closely at the HTML structure.

> - Separating the original prices from sale prices

Normal prices just have text directly under the `price_all`. Sale prices have two extra `span`s with a `was` and a `now` class.

> - How can I get the colors of the bags?

Each product has a `<div class="color_c">` with several `<a class="color_swatch">` tags. You can get the little circular picture from the `href` attribute, the name of the color from the `title` attribute, and the picture of the actual bag in that color looks closely related to the `href` and can probably be computed from it.